# How to support pashto font in pdf file

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextsharp for exporting .pdf file from C# application, but when I export the report fields with pashto comes blank.
Help me in this regard.
private void btnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"E:\Summary.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(gridresult.Columns.Count);
        doc.Open();
        BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
       
        var el = new Chunk();
        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfArialUniCode, 12);
        
        
        doc.AddLanguage("Urdu");
        for (int h = 0; h < gridresult.Columns.Count; h++) {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(gridresult.Columns[h].HeaderText));
        }
        table.HeaderRows = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridresult.Rows.Count; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < gridresult.Columns.Count; k++) {
                if (gridresult[k, i].Value != null) {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(gridresult[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();
```